# Regular expression to return numbers with floating point within parentheses

Tags: javascript

This is an example string

```
var s = "some text 123 [Price $20.99] some other text";
```

I want to get whatever numeric value is enclosed in square brackets along with decimal point.

What I have tried is

```
s.match(/\d+.\d+/);
```

and the results are 123, 20.99 but I don't want it to fetch numbers outside parentheses

can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Have to go but `/\[.*(\d+.\d+).*\]/` almost works doesnt match the start of the first number

Comment: thanks i got this to work `s.match(/\[*(\d+.\d+)\]/)[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of regular expressions!

Decimal dot is a [special character](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) in regular expressions, you need to escape it with backslash (`\`) if you want to match it literally.

This works for me (from Chrome JavaScript console):

```
> var s = "some text 123 [Price $20.99] some other text";
> s.match(/\d+\.\d+/)[0];
"20.99"
```

If you want to specifically only search within square brackets then you need to add those too; square brackets are also special so escaping is required. Also, if want to allow stuff between the brackets and the number, you'll need to specifically allow for that as well. Then you'll need to use capturing parenthesis, which means you'll need to access the match in slightly different fashion than in the first simple case. This works for me:

```
> var t = "Some text 123 and decimal number 12.34 and now [in square brackets 56.78] yada yada";
> t.match( /\[.*?(\d+\.\d+).*?\]/ )[1]
"56.78"
```

Let me walk the regexp through with you:

1. `\[` literal square bracket
2. `.*?` any character except newline, zero or more times, non-greedy
3. `(` start capture
4. `\d+` number, one or more times
5. `\.` literal dot
6. `\d+` number, one or more times
7. `)` end capture
8. `.*?` any character except newline, zero or more times, non-greedy
9. `\]` literal square bracket

You get an array in return. Array element `0` would again be the whole match, array element `1` is the content of the first capture.

Comment: You're welcome! Happy to help! :) Keep flexing that regexp muscle! https://xkcd.com/208/

Answer (score 0):

i got this to work

```
s.match(/\[*(\d+.\d+)\]/)[1]
```